# Cannot install Yeoman extension NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, git-bash

I'm configuring Git, and adding some extensions through NPM. I installed successfully [Gitmoji](https://github.com/carloscuesta/gitmoji), but now I'm having some trouble installing Yeoman Code generator to generate VSCode extension files.

When typing the command `npm install -g yo generator-code` the following occurs:

```
npm WARN deprecated debuglog@1.0.1: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated readdir-scoped-modules@1.1.0: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\PG&FX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\yo\\node_modules\\spawn-sync',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\PG&FX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\spawn-sync'] {      
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4082,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EBUSY',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\PG&FX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\yo\\node_modules\\spawn-sync'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\PG&FX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\yo',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\PG&FX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm5\internal'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\PG&FX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\yo\\node_modules\\rxjs\\dist\\esm5\\internal'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\PG&FX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\yo',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\PG&FX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\rxjs'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\PG&FX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\yo\\node_modules\\rxjs'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\PG&FX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-code\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\PG&FX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-code\node_modules'] {     
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\PG&FX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-code\\node_modules'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\PG&FX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c yodoctor
npm ERR! "FX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\.bin\" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
npm ERR! programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\yeoman-doctor\lib\cli.js'
npm ERR!     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: []
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v18.17.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\PG&FX\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-01T03_46_51_476Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to reinstall NPM, and Node.js. I also tried finding the `package.json` file to remove it and then re-try, but that file was never created in the first place. I also read that downgrading my Node.js would work, but I cannot seem to find the latest supported version for this package. On other question I've found a possible solution that required me to delete the `node_modules` and `package.json`, but again there was not such file; and deleting `node_modules` just broke npm, and made me unable to run the command `npm install` and `npm update`.

And since I'm using Git Bash I don't have the sudo command.

I found a similar problem to mine with this package, but sadly the only answer it had wasn't clear.

Possibly useful info:

- **OS:** Windows 10 Pro 22H2
- **Terminal (VSCode) :** Git Bash
- **Git version (IDK if useful):** 2.41.0.windows.3
- **Node.js version:** v18.17.0
- **NPM version:** 9.6.7